# How xml is used in android studio to display layout?

Tags: xml, android-studio

I am learning android studio.But what I've seen from files in my app,there are lots of xml files used as default.(I am using xml files android generated automatically.)
And what I dont understand is that xml is a data storing language,which means it cant do anything.(At least maybe that's why I learnt from w3schools)
So my question is:How exactly xml displays layouts then?